# Issues on parameters for jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to set my parameter as unique and dont continue with the next for every iteration, it means, for users those cannot be overlapped, so once I run multiple users the script sometimes overlap users and close sessions, please I would appreciate if you can help me on it

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

1. If you want to generate an unique value - take a look at [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) which produces [GUID-like structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which is supposed to be "unique". Alternatively you can use [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which returns current [timestamp in milliseconds since beginning of Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) which returns the number of current thread (virtual user) or any combination of all above.

   See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept
2. If you don't want the users to "overlap" take a look at [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller), it ensures that its children are executed by only one thread a a time